# ios 8 how do I make my custom inputAccessoryView stick to the top of the keyboard?

Tags: ios8, keyboard, inputaccessoryview

I have an app which was working under ios5 and had a custom inputAccessoryView with two buttons.  This was nicely attached to the top of the keyboard for my text editing page.  This was the code I used:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)aTextView {
    accToolbar.hidden = FALSE;
    if (aTextView.inputAccessoryView == nil) {
        aTextView.inputAccessoryView = accToolbar;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Now that I have updated my app to ios8 it no longer works correctly, I can't get it to stick to the top of the keyboard anymore.  I've searched for answers here and I've read the latest [InputViews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12) apple docs with no luck.

So the question is, how to create a custom inputAccessoryView that automatically locates at the top of the keyboard?